# What is wrong with this code that I made?

Tags: java

Can some one help me find what I did wrong in the code here. It is not working properly. I want to make a code to see if a number is prime or not. Here is the method:

```
public static boolean isPrime(int number)
{
  boolean result = true;
  for (int i = 2; i < number / 2 && result; i++)
  {
    if (number / i == 0)
    {
      result = false;
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: When you ask a question, you need to specify what exactly "not working properly" means, with expected and actual output, plus an exact copy of any error messages.

Comment: You need to learn _basics_.  Read about operators.

Answer (score 5):

There is difference between `/` and `%` operator; for the rest you are on your own.

As a hint:

```
4 / 2 == 2
4 % 2 == 0
```

Comment: What do you mean? Should I have used % instead...why?

Comment: % is modulo operator that gives you reminder of division

Answer (score 1):

Two issues I see.

1) `for (int i = 2; i < number / 2 && result; i++)` you are trying to compare integer i with boolean result.

2) `if (number / i == 0)` should be `if (number % i == 0)`. To check if a number is prime or not you need to check if a number has any integer except 1 and number itself which will divide the number giving remainder 0. `%` operator does that.

Answer (score 0):

Well your code should have been:

```
public static final SMALLEST_PRIME = 2;

private boolean isPrime(int number)
{
  for (int i = SMALLEST_PRIME; i * i <= number; i++)
  {
    if (number % i == 0)
    {
      return false;
    }
  }

  return true;
}
```

There's a difference between `/` and `%`. One is division operator and one is modulus operator. Modulus operator is what checks the remainder, and that's what is expected in checking for factors.

Comment: Thanks! I get it now. Using % see's if there is a remainder, since prime numbers will have a remainder! Appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

As 'Jigar' said you should use `%` instead of `/` to check if the number is dividable to i or not, In addition programmers usually take advantage of return in some situations including the one you are facing.
Take a look at this snippet :

```
public static boolean isPrime(int number)
{
  for (int i = 2; i < number / 2; i++)
  {
    if (number % i == 0)
    {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```